# Google Cardboard for Unity renders only one light source

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, light, google-cardboard

I downloaded Google Cardboard SDK for Unity. In the demo scene, I put 2 light sources (spot with default settings). As you can see in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/opVEl.jpg), the two light sources are rendered in unity editor and game mode, but only one light source is rendered on my Android 5.1.1 phone.

Is the "one light source max" a Cardboard limitation I am not aware of? Or am I doing something wrong?

Thank you for your help

Comment: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1104897/google-cardboard-for-unity-seems-to-renders-only-o.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a Cardboard limitation.  Doublecheck that you have enabled more than one pixel light source in the project's Quality settings for Android.

Comment: Thanks a lot. My pixel light source  quality setting was set to 4 already. But your comment help me in my research. I found that if I set the Render Mode of each of my light source to Important (instead of "Auto") it fixed the problem. Now both light source appear in my game on Android!